# Laravel 5.4 saving pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm currently trying to save my pivot table but this error keep occurring.

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'role_role_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `role_user` (`role_role_id`, `user_id`) values (1, 1))

I dont know why role_role_id is in double state

Here is my Models

Role

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

User

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

Controller

```
   $user = new User([
          'name'            => $request->get('username'),
          'email'           => $request->get('email'),
          'password'        => $request->get('password'),
          'role_id'         => $request->get('role_id'),         
        ]);

        $user->save();

        $role = Role::find(1);
        $role->users()->save($role);
```

Migration

```
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('role_id');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });



Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('role_id');
            $table->string('role');
            //Required
            $table->string('created_by');
            $table->string('updated_by');
            $table->string('is_active');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('role_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
        });
```

P.S. I just followed the eloquent documentation of laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Comment: Did you added this `protected $primaryKey = 'role_id';` to your Role model ?

Comment: No I declared it as  public $primaryKey='role_id';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many-to-many you should use [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method:

```
$user = User::create($request->all());
$user->roles()->attach(1);
```

Also, change this:

```
$table->increments('role_id');
```

to:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

And remove this line:

```
$table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
```

Then recreate the tables . `primary` will not work for the pivot table foreign keys.

Comment: Tried this but still it occurs 

(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'role_role_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `role_user` (`role_role_id`, `user_id`) values (2, 17))

Comment: I already remove but still this "column not found role_role_id" is keep comming , I already migrated refresh and composer dump autoload yet nothing happen